# Must declare the scalar variable error when calling stored proc

Tags: sql, netbeans

I'm having trouble getting this SP call to work.  It worked previously and no changes were made, but I cannot get it to work for the life of me now. 
The error code I'm getting is:

```
Error code 137, SQL state S0002: Must declare the scalar variable "@AppName".
```

This is using netbeans sql editor.  if I hard code the AppName variable, it then throws the same error for AppVer.  A coworker can use the exact code and it works fine in his non-netbeans ide (I think vis studio?).  This leads me to believe that it's a netbeans issue rather than the code itself.

Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @AppName nvarchar(100) = 'Excel ASAP Utilities';
DECLARE @AppVer nvarchar(50) = '3.07b';
DECLARE @AppManufacture nvarchar(100) = null;
DECLARE @RequestedByID dbo.UserID = 'userid';
DECLARE @RequestDescription nvarchar(3500) = 'This is a test';
DECLARE @NumberNeededFor int = null;
DECLARE @AssignToID dbo.UserID = '?';
DECLARE @RequestType_ID int = 6;
DECLARE @LCM_ID int = 50;
DECLARE @ProcessID int = 3;
DECLARE @RM_ID int;

EXECUTE dbo.Request_InsertNewShortForm
                                @AppName,
                                @AppVer,
                                @AppManufacture,
                                @RequestedByID,
                                @RequestDescription,
                                @NumberNeededFor,
                                @AssignToID,
                                @RequestType_ID,
                                @LCM_ID,
                                @ProcessID,
                                @RM_ID OUTPUT;
SELECT 'Return Value' = @RM_ID;
```

Comment: What is that supposed to do: `SELECT 'Return Value' = @RM_ID;`?

Comment: pass a return value, disregard it though, the error happens if I take that out as well.

Comment: I assume it's within the proc `dbo.Request_InsertNewShortForm` that the variable is not being declared, where's the proc's code?

Comment: I don't have that code, I'm calling someone else's code which he can get working copy/pasting this exact code into his ide.  I've tried another machine with netbeans, same error.